# Laravel query delete relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My model is `Patient -> Sample`, I delete a patient, I query deleted patient by `withTrashed()`, But don't query  sample for deleted patient by `withTrashed();`

Patient_Controller

```
class Patient_Controller extends Controller{

public function query(Request $request){

    $result = Patient_Model::withTrashed();
        ->orderBy("updated_at","desc")
        ->Paginate(15)
        ->toJson();

   return $result;
}
```

But in Sample_Controller

```
class Sample_Controller extends Controller{

public function query(Request $request){

    $result = Sample_Model::with('patient')
        ->withTrashed()
        ->orderBy("updated_at","desc")
        ->Paginate(15)
        ->toJson();

   return $result;
}
```

But with not find delete Patient, so My sample don't get patient info

Comment: What is `with(['relationship_belong'])`? And can you show your `Patient_Model` and `Sample_Model` please?

Also, not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: with(['relationship_belong']),relationship_belong is Sample_Model belongsTo function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to include trashed patients in your with? If so, then try the following.

```
public function query(Request $request){

  $result = Sample_Model::with(['patient' => function($q) {
        $q->withTrashed();
    }])
    ->withTrashed()
    ->orderBy("updated_at","desc")
    ->Paginate(15)
    ->toJson();

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Yes,you are right, I success,Sorry,My english is so bad,Thanks you.

Comment: can you help my other question ? thanks......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005477/laravel5-1-query-relationshipseloquent-orm